# Is it Polynomial time algorithm

Tags: algorithm, np

If an algorithm's input size is 2^n and the algorithm runs in $O(n2^n)$ time. In this case, can we say that the algorithm runs in polynomial time with respect to input size?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that would be an O(k log k)-time algorithm, where k = 2^n.

Comment: Thanks, @David  So, I could say it is a polynomial time or pseudopolynomial? I am confused between these two.

Comment: A good question and a good answer - everything depends on the right definitions; I always found it somewhat puzzling that, for instance, for matrix multiplication algorithms, the runtime bound is usually stated in terms of `n` where the input is of size `n*n`.

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER Polynomial. An example of a pseudopolynomial running time is O(k^log k).